# On Premise Agent does not download all NPM packages

Tags: npm, azure-devops

**Edit**: 2018-02-28 - add screen shot of build definition

I am having a problem with an on premise VSTS Agent.  When 'npm install' runs, it only installs about 20% of the packages.  the command does not error out.  If I run the same NPM install command when I remote into the machine all the packages are installed.  I used the same steps manually that are in the [Visual Studio Team Services Hosted Images](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation) scripts. Specifically [Install-NodeLts.ps1](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/scripts/Installers/Install-NodeLts.ps1)

I need to get the local agent running so our builds will complete.

npm/5.6.0 node/v8.9.4 win32 x64

You can see below it says: 'added 559 packages in 37.875s', but when run npm install from command line via RDP, it installs 2419 packages.

I have tried:

- re-install NPM as a task
- run npm install twice as two different tasks
- run npm install from a command task
- run agent as my same user account

[image]

Partial output log:

`2018-02-27T21:30:59.6386335Z ##[section]Starting: npm install
2018-02-27T21:30:59.6396849Z ==============================================================================
2018-02-27T21:30:59.6397102Z Task         : npm
2018-02-27T21:30:59.6397398Z Description  : Install and publish npm packages, or run an npm command. Supports npmjs.com and authenticated registries like Package Management.
2018-02-27T21:30:59.6397690Z Version      : 1.0.10
2018-02-27T21:30:59.6397884Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-02-27T21:30:59.6398144Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613746)
2018-02-27T21:30:59.6398400Z ==============================================================================
2018-02-27T21:31:00.7066189Z [command]C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" --version"
2018-02-27T21:31:02.6879301Z 5.6.0
2018-02-27T21:31:07.0100259Z [command]C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" config list"
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1937476Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1938350Z npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1938614Z npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1938859Z npm verb cli   'prefix',
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1939038Z npm verb cli   '-g' ]
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1939210Z npm info using npm@5.6.0
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1939414Z npm info using node@v8.9.4
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1939594Z npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1939806Z npm info ok 
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1940065Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1940314Z npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1940577Z npm verb cli   'C:\\npm\\prefix\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1940790Z npm verb cli   'config',
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1941046Z npm verb cli   'list' ]
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1941258Z npm info using npm@5.6.0
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1941470Z npm info using node@v8.9.4
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1941711Z npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1941956Z npm info ok 
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1942165Z ; cli configs
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1942384Z metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1942647Z scope = ""
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1942849Z user-agent = "npm/5.6.0 node/v8.9.4 win32 x64"
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1942977Z 
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1943141Z ; environment configs
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1943350Z cache = "C:\\npm\\cache"
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1943529Z loglevel = "verbose"
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1943712Z prefix = "C:\\npm\\prefix"
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1943927Z userconfig = "D:\\VSTSAgent\\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.129.1\\_work\\2\\npm\\187.npmrc"
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1944096Z 
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1944268Z ; builtin config undefined
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1944399Z 
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1944626Z ; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1944941Z ; cwd = D:\VSTSAgent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.129.1\_work\2\s\Web
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1945215Z ; HOME = C:\Users\bolducp
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1945445Z ; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1945592Z 
2018-02-27T21:31:09.1947815Z [command]C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" install"
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2618021Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2618358Z 
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2623471Z > react-bootstrap-select@0.14.0 postinstall D:\VSTSAgent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.129.1\_work\2\s\Web\node_modules\react-bootstrap-select
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2624421Z npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2624674Z > jsx jsx/ dist/
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2624944Z npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2625391Z 
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2625873Z ["Select"]
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2627029Z added 559 packages in 37.875s
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2636988Z npm verb cli   'prefix',
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2637434Z npm verb cli   '-g' ]
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2639621Z npm info using npm@5.6.0
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2639731Z npm info using node@v8.9.4
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2639837Z npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2640063Z npm info ok 
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2640199Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2640352Z npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2640480Z npm verb cli   'C:\\npm\\prefix\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2640597Z npm verb cli   'install' ]
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2640700Z npm info using npm@5.6.0
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2640835Z npm info using node@v8.9.4
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2640945Z npm verb npm-session 7bedb538a9b4e7b7
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2641065Z npm info lifecycle company-project@1.0.0~preinstall: company-project@1.0.0
2018-02-27T21:31:50.2641230Z npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/moment 375ms (from cache)
...
2018-02-27T21:31:50.3412460Z npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
2018-02-27T21:31:50.3412559Z npm info ok 
2018-02-27T21:31:50.3416231Z ##[section]Finishing: npm install`

Comment: Are all 2419 packages in the package.json file? Could you share a screenshot of your build definition? How long it takes when you run `npm install` manually and in VSTS?

Comment: The npm cache is shared by multiple agents on the same machine (`cache = "C:\\npm\\cache"` in your log). Could it be that they have been downloaded already?

Comment: I am pretty sure the packages are in the cache, however, they are not in the node_modules folder after the 'npm install' task runs as part of the build.  The following steps fail because it cannot find dependent modules, ie es6-promise.  There is only one agent installed on this machine.

Comment: There are 114 dev dependencies and 27 dependencies listed in the package.json file.  After manually running npm install, there are 1399 package folders in the node_modules folder.  I assume 2419 number comes from the requested packages and all of their dependencies. For example, webpack has 12 modules downloaded in node_modules/webpack/node_modules

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I would note when I ran the same build definition against the hosted build agent, it worked.  The npm install task took almost 10 minutes, but it did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting up the hosted agent, I had modified the build definition to include an environment variable NODE_ENV=production. When the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production, npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies.